# Building Vim .debs on Ubuntu

Tags: vim, compilation

From the [vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Building_Vim) site:

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial libssl-dev
sudo apt-get build-dep vim
hg clone http://hg.debian.org/hg/pkg-vim/vim
cd vim
hg checkout unstable
debian/rules update-orig
dpkg-buildpackage -i -I
cd ..
```

It looks like there are no commands called `debian/rules` on my system.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you trying to create a .deb?

Comment: Yeah. I ended up using checkinstall, it's much easier, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The *wikia* vim *tips* site is not complete and ignores all the hard work of packagers of vim. The standard way to build a Debian or Ubuntu binary package is from a source package. Using source packages are by far a better solution for most people.

[pkg_basics.en.html#s-sourcebuild](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html#s-sourcebuild)

The upstream site https://code.google.com/p/vim/ is indeed hosted with mercurial and there is a github clone https://github.com/b4winckler/vim however very few people really need the most bleeding edge sources. The build-deps are pretty significant.

The Debian vim maintainers also use mercurial to maintain their packaging per debian/README.source at http://hg.debian.org/hg/pkg-vim/vim and Debian developers with commit access can help with the packaging that uses quilt to maintain patches at the URL ssh://hg.debian.org/hg/pkg-vim/vim Information about the Debian binary packages created from hg.debian.org (also used as a base for Ubuntu) can be found: http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=vim

For Ubuntu a much better way is using a PPA (personal package archive) of someone that is familiar with the 7.4 sources, how packaging works, the latest patches and the latest dependencies. Very recently (Aug 2013) vim 7.4 landed in the future Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy archive available for everyone to install using standard methods so no effort is needed at all. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim Quite a few PPAs contain vim builds already. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=vim but there are not many current 7.4 builds backported all the way to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise yet as described https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates. As described in the following bug I tried to build it for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS precise since that is what I use on my main machine. With a three line patch I got it working. I haven't put it up in a PPA yet. The bug formally requests the backport so if you care about this please vote it up and/or comment on it so the bug will get more attention. https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1211971

If you find a PPA you like, for example like this one https://launchpad.net/~cjohnston/+ppa-packages you can add it by typing "sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cjohnston/ppa; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade".